# Porter Cable NiCd 18V batteries - Lithium replacements?

Tags: powertools, battery

Does anyone here have any experience with these tools and battery options? What about chargers? I understand the need for a different charger; my specific question is whether anyone has experience with these (apparently after-market) PC18B replacements.

I have a [rather old now] kit of Porter Cable circular saw, drill/driver, reciprocating saw, flashlight that uses the PC18B batteries - which have become officially discontinued (besides suffering from all the problems of NiCd batteries in the first place.)

I see Lithium options listed on various sites as PC18BL and PC18BLX; Porter Cable customer service says that there are no Li options for PC18B tools.

Many thanks in advance,
Donald.

Comment: I don’t know about Porter Cable specifically, but most tool manufacturers changed the dock going from NiCd to Li... to make it perfectly clear what charger to use.   While the tools don’t care as much what kind of battery, chargers do need to charge the correct... or the battery catches fire and burns.

Comment: Lithiums are super not interchangeable with nickel-cadmium.  They require a totally different charging system in order for the lithium battery to not catch fire and meltdown.  NiCds don't explode, obviously.  It is possible to build a lithium pack that can run a NiCd 18V tool, but it needs onboard electronics to not explode from overuse, and it *definitely* needs its own separate charger.